# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 6426 pos 12: 'child == _child'" is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, bluetooth-lowenergy, indoor-positioning-system

I am currently building a mobile project called BLE Indoor Positioning System. However, I am suffered from a problem above and I have not been able to solve it. Would really appreciate if someone could explain for me what this error is?

Source code: https://github.com/BuiHuyTam/BLE-Indoor-Positioning-System

I have tried so many different ways to solve this problem. However, it didn't work

1. Upgrade flutter version
2. Using MaterialApp instead of GetMaterialApp